# Google reCAPTCHA either not clickable or with white container

Tags: javascript, html, css, recaptcha

I have found an issue, which keeps driving me crazy.
To avoid spam, I've implemented *Google reCAPTCHA* in my website and added it to my form. I'm currently using it with `javascript` like this:

In the head:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var captchaContainer = null;
    var loadCaptcha = function () {
        captchaContainer = grecaptcha.render('recaptcha', {
            'sitekey': '[myKey]',
            'callback': function (response) {
                console.log(response);
            }
        });
    };
</script>
```

In the body (in my form):

```
<form action="validation.php" method="POST">
    <input placeholder="Your Name" type="text" name="name" />
    // ...
    <div id="recaptcha"></div>
    <input type="submit" id="submitButton" name="submit" value="absenden" />
</form>
<script src="https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api.js?onload=loadCaptcha&render=explicit" async defer></script>
```

But unfortunately the widget renders some **white space** below the *reCAPTCHA* as seen in this screenshot:

[image]

I've tried to add a `z-index: -1` to the `#recaptcha div` and then it looks exactly the way I want it to look, but it is not clickable anymore.

Can someone please tell, what I am doing wrong?

Comment: Could you recreate in a codepen or post the site to debug?

Comment: Yes, having access to a live page would make the debugging so much easier.

Comment: i think i might work a bit more on the page and try to solve it another time, when i got more time on my hands.

Answer (score 2):

I have this issue here and, in my case, it is not working with Chrome when Device Toolbar is activated within DevTools. Simply disabling device toolbar makes recaptcha work again and also I have confirmed that it does work in real devices. It looks like a bug in DevTools.

It is a really annoying behavior and I could not really solve it, but this discovery made me move on to more important issues, since it would not be a problem in production.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if you have exactly the same issue with positioning. On my page recaptcha was hiding behind `<p>` element which wouldn't allow clicking, because almost all form elements use float. So try using

`#recaptcha{ 
   clear: both; 
}`

to prevent overlay and unpositionable behavior. Or assign float to it if required.

Answer (score 0):

Found solution. Yes, this is bug in Chrome DevTools and mobile screen emulator. You can fix it - changing device scale from 75% to 100%. Supposed this problem with iframe and touch coordinates when used zoom.